# Get frames from the camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera, aar

Actually, I'm writing an Android library for Godot Engine.

Which steps do I envision?

1- Get the frames from the camera.

2- Convert frames to Bitmap.

3- Resize Bitmap if required (optional).

4- Send to Godot Engine.

I'm currently stuck on step one, can anyone give me a full example of getting the frames from the camera?

I don't want to display frames in Android Studio I just want to get them from the code

Note:

I am using Java version 11.

Edit:

I tried this code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private Button bCapture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bCapture = findViewById(R.id.bCapture);
        bCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                capturePhoto();
            }
        });
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                startCameraX(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, getExecutor());

    }

    Executor getExecutor() {
        return ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
    }


    private void startCameraX(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider)
    {
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .build();

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(getExecutor(), new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
            @Override
            public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {

                Log.d("TAG", "analyze: got the frame at: " + image.getImageInfo().getTimestamp());
                image.close();
            }
        });

        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, imageCapture);
    }

    private void capturePhoto()
    {
        imageCapture.takePicture(getExecutor(), new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image)
            {
                Log.d("Test"," one success capture");
                super.onCaptureSuccess(image);
                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(image);
                Log.d("Test"," Capture Success ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                super.onError(exception);
                Log.d("Test"," Error capture");
            }
        });
    }

    //convert to Bitmap
    private Bitmap getBitmap(ImageProxy image)
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        buffer.rewind();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        byte[] clonedBytes = bytes.clone();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(clonedBytes, 0, clonedBytes.length);
    }
}
```

But it failed because the app was closing abruptly when it started.

build.gradle (Module: MyApplication3.app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication3'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication3"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


    def cameraxVersion = "1.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${cameraxVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${cameraxVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${cameraxVersion}"

    // CameraX View class
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha25'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="32">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit:
As for closing the app when it started, it was because this line was missing:

```xml
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication3"
```

As for capturing the image I tried to print the exception here:

```java
public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) 
{
    super.onError(exception);
    Log.d("Test"," Error capture " + exception.getMessage());
}
```

Output:

Error capture **Camera is closed.**

Comment: You may go through the [CameraX API documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax)

Comment: @RickyMo thanks for your reply.
Can you give me an example of how to get the frames directly without showing them?

Comment: Just follow the documentation, it has the example you need. You need the `ImageCapture` use case and exclude the `Preview` use case.

Comment: @RickyMo 
Sorry for the trouble. But keep in mind I am a novice in android studio.
So I don't know how to capture the camera in CameraX and I tried this example but failed:
https://akhilbattula.medium.com/android-camerax-java-example-aeee884f9102

So can you give me a complete example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.